# Right way to design database to stop Hibernate from making unneccessary joins for One to one relationships

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having a trouble with one to one relationships, which results in unnecessary joins of table whose data I do not need in many instances. And as far as I have found, it seems clear that there is no way by which we can ask hibernate not to join certain tables or keep them as lazy loading.

I found two solutions for this problem:

1. Scalar native sql seems to be an option but that too is not a good idea.
2. Making one side as OneToMany, and return a list. That is ugly.

So, I was wondering, is there any way by which making changes in database tables and their relationships, that would help in solving this problem. For example, my current table design is like following image:

[image]

Here, whenever I load **Order** then it also automatically joins **Shipment** and **BillingInfo** table but skips joining **Customer** and **ShippingAddress** table.

From this I thought of adding **FK** column for **Shipment** and **BillingInfo** in **Order** table but that seems to be kind of weird. Because for an order, it is not necessary that BillingInfo and Shipment information will be available. For such entries which may be gets filled and may be not, adding a FK column seems to be like putting extra burden on **Order** table.

-> For this I want to take opinion of experts about how exactly tables should be designed to handle such scenarios.

And similar to this I have 2-3 more tables which also gets joined and fetched along with Order like Shipment and BillingInfo. Which makes fetching of Order table records very bulky.

Code for these in **Order** entity class is as follows:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
public Shipment getShipment() {
    return shipment;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ShippingAddressId")
public Address getShippingAddress() {
    return shippingAddress;
}
```

And code in **Shipment** entity is as follows:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "OrderId", nullable = false)
public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}
```